# Update BigQuery Schema / Add New Column in Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery, schema

I have a need to update a BigQuery table schema through Java. The change will be additive (only adding new columns).

I am struggling to find a way to achieve this. In Python it is possible like this:

```
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request

original_schema = table.schema
new_schema = original_schema[:]  # creates a copy of the schema
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('phone', 'STRING'))

table.schema = new_schema
table = client.update_table(table, ['schema'])  # API request
```

On the page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas, it is stated to use the patch endpoint for this task.

An issue was raised to improve the patch API but I am not aware of the outcome https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1564

This is a link to the Patch Class Documentation: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Tables.Patch.html#set-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea in Java would be the same as in the Python example you shared, i.e. obtaining the current schema and adding a new column to it. You can achieve this with the snippet I prepared, which you can see below:

```
// Instantiate the BQ client
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

// Get the table, schema and fields from the already-existing table
Table table = bigquery.getTable(TableId.of("PROJECT_ID", "DATASET", "TABLE"));
Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();
FieldList fields = schema.getFields();

// Create the new field
Field newField = Field.of("column2", LegacySQLTypeName.STRING);

// Create a new schema adding the current fields, plus the new one
List<Field> field_list = new ArrayList<Field>();
for (Field f : fields) {
    field_list.add(f);
}
field_list.add(newField);
Schema newSchema = Schema.of(field_list);

// Update the table with the new schema
Table updatedTable = table.toBuilder().setDefinition(StandardTableDefinition.of(newSchema)).build().update();
```

This code is making use of the `com.google.cloud.bigquery` package (see its [documentation here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html)). Then, it specifies the schema definition as done in the sample from the [tables documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition), and finally updates it.

Comment: Thanks so much, will get back to you on whether it works but looks like exactly what I need

Comment: I am glad I could be of help! If after all, the answer is useful for you, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Although this does do what I need it to, I am unfortunately using the Apache Beam framework which does not allow the com.google.cloud.bigquery package. Instead it makes use of its own beam package and another google package: com.google.api.services.bigquery

I again am struggling to find a way to do it through this package, do you happen to know? Thanks again !

This is a link to the top level docs https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi @SimSimmer; thank you for accepting my answer. I agree that this works for the BigQuery Java client library but does not necessarily work for the Apache Beam environment. In any case, being it the case that this is a completely different topic/issue, I would recommend you to post a new question, so that this is treated as a different issue and you can add the appropriate Dataflow/Apache Beam tags.

Comment: Also, so that you can start working on that separate issue, I am not sure if it would be possible to achieve something like what my answer suggests. Instead, you may have to add columns dynamically with the BigQuery load jobs, by changing the schema with the new columns, as explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_column_when_you_overwrite_or_append_data).

Answer (score 1):

I also managed to do it through the other Google BigQuery package:

```
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential;
    try {
        credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport,
                jsonFactory);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
        credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
    }

    Bigquery.Tables bqTables = new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).build().tables();
    Bigquery.Tables.Get bqTableGet = bqTables.get(this.project, this.dataset, this.tablePrefix + strDate);

    Table bqTable = bqTableGet.execute();
    bqTable.setSchema(this.schema);

    Bigquery.Tables.Patch bqTablePatch = bqTables.patch(this.project, this.dataset, this.tablePrefix + strDate, bqTable);
    bqTablePatch.execute();
```